# ResourceBundle not found for MessageSource

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm not able to locate the message source in my app. I have set the following configuration

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list><value>resources.dev</value></list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

There will be more .properties files that will be added.

The dev.properties file is located at `ROOT/resources/dev.properties` where ROOT is the webapp

The dev.properties has to be in `ROOT/resources/dev.properties`

dev.properties contains

```
test.url="external.url.com"
```

In my controller I'm trying to access the message as

```
messageSource.getMessage("test.url", new Object[]{}, Locale.getDefault())
```

I'm getting the following exception

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'test.url' for locale 'en_US'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just using this in your XML:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="resources/dev"/>
</bean>
```

Then try putting your dev.properties file in ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/resources (where ROOT is the root directory of the exploded webapp).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually have the basenames as a list as more properties file are going to be added. And I cannot change the resources folder location. I have updated the question.

Comment: Your resource bundles have to be in the classpath. ROOT/ of the webapp is not in the classpath. See this JavaDoc:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29

If you can't move them you may need to write your own MessageSource implementation to load them based on file paths.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html